# Special Python dict with object IDs

Tags: python, inheritance, dictionary

I want to create a special dictionary which uses object IDs as keys, like this:

```
class ObjectIdDict(dict):

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        super(ObjectIdDict, self).__setitem__(id(key), value)

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        super(ObjectIdDict, self).__getitem__(id(key))
```

But if I run the following test, I get an error:

```
class ObjectIdDictTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_get_and_set(self):
        dict_to_test = ObjectIdDict()
        class Something:
            def __init__(self):
                self.x = 1
        s = Something()
        dict_to_test[s.x] = "message"
        self.assertEqual(dict_to_test[s.x], "message")
```

Error message:

```
AssertionError: None != 'message'
```

What is wrong here?

**Background:**

The reason for creating such an exotic dict is that I want to store validation errors for each field of an object and want to avoid field names as strings: `domain_object.errors[domain_object.field1]` otherwise field names as strings (`domain_object.errors["field1"]`) would be bad for refactoring and code completion.

ΤΖΩΤΖΙΟΥ:

> I'm certain you don't get anything by
>   using  IDs. `obj.field1= 1;
>   print(id(obj.field1)); obj.field1= 2;
>   print(id(obj.field1))`

If I would not use IDs, the key would be the **value** of the variable, not its address. This would lead to errors if two fields had the same value:

```
def test_ordinary_dict(self):
    dict_to_test = {}
    class Something:
        def __init__(self):
            self.x = 1
            self.y = 1 # same value as self.x!
    s = Something()
    dict_to_test[s.x] = "message for x"
    dict_to_test[s.y] = "message for y"
    self.assertEqual(dict_to_test[s.x], "message for x")

    # fails because dict_to_test[s.x] == dict_to_test[1] what results in:
    # "message for y"
```

It is not critical that changing a variables value lead to a new address since the validation result is no longer valid after that.

Comment: Can you also explain why you want to use object ID? So far I can only see downsides for this.

Comment: @Sorin Sbarnea I've added an explanation.

Comment: I'm certain you don't get anything by using IDs. `obj.field1= 1; print(id(obj.field1)); obj.field1= 2; print(id(obj.field1))` You do know that Python does not have variables (as in C or Basic), just objects and names for those objects, right?

Comment: You example makes no sense at all: after you've assigned `1` to `self.x` and `self.y` they both have both the same value and the same id.

Comment: @Duncan Thanks for pointing this out. You're absolutely right - my approach is completely wrong!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`__getitem__` must return the result:

```
def __getitem__(self, key):
  return super(ObjectIdDict, self).__getitem__(id(key))
  #^^^^^
```

Without a `return`, the implicit return value is `None`, and therefore `oiddict[key] is None` for all keys.